# What exactly does my body do with oxygen? Why do I need it?

Tags: hematology, lungs

I know that my body and brain need oxygen in order to survive. If I stop breathing, my lungs (and blood) can't distribute oxygen to my body anymore, and I could get brain damage and die. What exactly is being done to the oxygen, and why do I need it?

Comment: it is expected that you atleast do some research before asking a question here,this is a starting point for research into this subject https://www.nursingtimes.net/clinical-archive/respiratory-clinical-archive/every-breath-you-take-the-process-of-breathing-explained-08-01-2018/

Answer (score 1):

**Oxygen is used to oxidize (burn) molecules and generate energy.**

A fire combines oxygen with carbon containing molecules (like coal) and releases energy (heat) as well as carbon dioxide and water.  A fire needs oxygen or it will stop.

You need oxygen because inside your cells is an oxidation process much like a fire.  Oxygen is combined with carbon containing molecules like sugar.  When they combine, energy is released.  As opposed to a fire which releases the energy as heat, your body captures the energy in a chemical called ATP that can then be used in the body to do a little dance, and make a little love.

The oxidation reaction in your body also releases CO2 and H2O which you exhale.